# "Toast"-like alerts in a Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to replace the following line:

```
   alert("Success!");
```

with something similar to Android-style toasts (Meaning, a non-interruptive success message somewhere on the page). There are many JQuery solutions for this problem (see [here](http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/demo/demo.html)), however I am having trouble using them from a Chrome Extension background page.

I have also tried injecting it into the current page, but this is not simple and also not working (because I need to inject JQuery, then the plugin, then me calling the plugin) and this becomes a little ridiculous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html).

Comment: No they aren't. They sit in the corner until the user closes them and they don't block actions in the tab.

Comment: However, they exist outside of the browser (on the desktop) and the message I'm sending isn't that important. I'm trying trying to send some sort of confirmation of the user's click. Is it possible with a toast in the browser?

Comment: Toast style notifications are best for feedback on the currently viewed page. Since you are triggering them from a background page it isn't associated with the currently viewable tab and you should use desktop notifications. If you want it to be less intrusive you can automatically close it after five seconds.

Comment: Desktop notifications are a decently easy solution, but the confirmation IS actually associated with the current tab, so I would prefer a toast if possible.

Comment: If you really want to you can use toast. It will be more work to inject all the needed code to generate the same effect that desktop notifications give you out of the box however.

Answer (score 2):

Desktop Notifications still seem to be best, however the link in the answer is broken.

Below is a working example of how to create a basic Desktop Notification from a Chrome Extension and a link to the docs for more:

```
const notificationId = 'abc123'

const options = {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: 'chrome-extension://dklpcjlnpcnegggninnhpbhpneialgci/src/shared/icon.png',
    title: 'Hey',
    message: 'Hello world',
}

const callback = notificationId => console.log('notificationId: ', notificationId)

chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, options, callback)
```

More here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/